# Passing a list to a method inside a class from another class in order to modify said list and pass back to the original class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, oop, methods

I am writing a novel **Blackjack** program for my online portfolio that creates cards from random.

In order to not create duplicate cards in one round I have created a list that stores the cards that have already been created. The new random card is then checked against the cards contained inside the dealed_cards list, if it is duplicate the method is called again and a new card assigned.

My dealed_cards list is initiated inside a class that creates the round and then is passed from class to class as a list that can re-initialized at the beginning of a new round of game play. However the list is not passing correctly into the method within the class that assigns new card values.

Some ways that I have tried to pass the list in are:
(self, dealed_cards), with this I get error

```
TypeError deal_card_out() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dealed_cards'
With (self, dealed_cards = [], *args)
```

which at least works but doesn't necessarily pass the list correctly, when I try to print the dealed_cards list out from within the method before modifying it I get an empty list.

with **(self, *dealed_cards)** this returns the list as a tuple and doesn't pass it correct. and finally with **(self, dealed_cards = [])** result: still not passing in the list dealed_cards from inside the function

Here is a test block of code I broke off from the main program in order to test this method.

```py
class deal_card(object):

def __init__(self):
    pass
def deal_card_out(self, dealed_cards = []): 
    print("This is a test print statement at the beginning of this method to test that dealed_cards was passed in correctly.")
    print(dealed_cards)
    card_one_face_value = 'Seven'
    card_one_suit_value = 'Clubs'

    for _ in dealed_cards:
        if card_one_face_value == [_[0]]:
            print(f"This is a test print statement inside the for loop within deal_card out, it willl print out [_[0]] inside this for loop: {[_[0]]}")
            if card_one_suit_value == [_[1]]:
                print("test loop successful")
            else:
                print(f"This is a test print statement inside the for loop within deal_card out, it willl print out [_[0]] inside this for loop: {[_[0]]}") 
                pass
        else:
            print(f"this is a test print statement inside the for loop within deal_card out it will print out dealed_cards[_[1]] to show what is happening inside this loop: {[_[1]]}")
            pass
        dealed_cards.append([card_one_face_value,card_one_suit_value])

        print("This is a test print inside of deal_card_out, it prints list dealed_cards after method modifies the list")
        print(dealed_cards)
        return [dealed_cards,card_one_face_value,card_one_suit_value]

dealed_cards = [['Place','Holder'],['Seven','Clubs']]
print("this is a test print statement outside of the method to test that     dealed_cards is being passed in correctly")
print(dealed_cards)
test_run = deal_card.deal_card_out(dealed_cards)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong with the method. "self" does not need to be placed in the method definition. For some reason placing self in the method call didn't pass the list dealed_cards correctly. Also, dealed_cards can just be passed as dealed_cards, not dealed_cards = []. 
So the new correct method definition is `def deal_card_out(dealed_cards):`
The for loop was also misbehaving, the test statement `if card_one_face_value == [_[0]]:` needed to be changed to `if card_one_face_value == _[0]:` otherwise you are testing with brackets around seven, the string inside that nested list.